# How to put Json inside asynctask - Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have a json function that connects to a database and returns a result. It does this about 15 times or for how many comments there are in the database. The json function is inside a while loop, and repeats itself until all the comments have been taken from the database or until it reached 15 comments. The problem is when the app loads the comments it does it during the onCreate part of the app. I want the app to load and then the json function to load in the back. I know I can do this with an asynctask but I am not familiar with them. So I was hoping someone would be able to tell me how to place this code into a asynctask.

```
     UserFunctions CollectComments = new UserFunctions();
                     JSONObject json = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);




                         int commentCycle = 1;

                  // check for comments  
                     try {  
                         if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                             registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                             String res2 = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                             if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 

                                 String numberOfComments = json.getString(KEY_NUMBER_OF_COMMENTS);


                                 String offsetNumberDb = db.getOffsetNumber();


                                int numberOfComments2 = Integer.parseInt(numberOfComments) - Integer.parseInt(offsetNumberDb);
                                offsetNumber = offsetNumberDb;

                                 //if comment number is less than 15 or equal to 15
                                 if(numberOfComments2 <= 15){




                                 while (commentCycle <= numberOfComments2){

JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);



                    TextView commentView = new TextView(this);
                                      commentView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams commentViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                         commentViewParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 20);
                                    commentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_bg);
                                      commentView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                             commentBox.addView(commentView, commentViewParams);



                                 verify2 = verify2 + 1;

                                offsetNumber = json2.getString(KEY_OFFSET_NUMBER);
                                commentCycle = commentCycle + 1;

                             }//end while
                           }//end if comment number is less than or equal to 15

                                }//end if key is == 1
                             else{
                                 // Error in registration
                                 registerErrorMsg.setText(json.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                             }//end else
                         }//end if
                     } //end try

                     catch (JSONException e) { 
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }//end catch
```

All this code works but I want it running in the background not during the apps oncreate some one please try putting this into a asynctask or at least help me understand how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your while loop in a new Thread or Async Task. Here is how is will work

```
    public class JsonWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //your while loop goes here

    }


  }
```

Just before the while loop in your current code you should call `new JsonWork().execute()`. So that it would execute the while loop in a new AsyncTask Thread.